# SQL Debit and Credit tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I got a database project from my university to finish, but I am stack at the structure of debit and credit table that how to make it in SQL Server, my code is shown here:

```
create table AcCat
(
    CatID smallint Primary Key,
    CatName nvarchar(20)
)

Create Table Accounts
(
    AcID int Primary key,
    AcNumber int,
    AcName nvarchar(20),
    AcCategory smallint references AcCat(CatID)
)

Create Table Transactions
(
    TrnRef bigint primary key identity (1,1),
    TrnDate datetime
)

Create Table Voucher
(
    VID bigint primary key identity (1,1),
    TranRef bigint references Transactions(TrnRef),
    AccountNo int references Accounts(AcID),
    DrCr nvarchar(2),
    Amount money,
    Narration nvarchar(100)
)

Create Table Voucher_2 
(
    V2ID bigint primary key identity (1,1),
    V2TranRef bigint references Transactions(TrnRef),
    V2DebitAc int references Accounts(AcID),
    V2CreditAc int references Accounts(AcID),
    Amount money,
    Narration nvarchar(100)
)
```

I don't know above table structure are correct or not, but I am stuck at the `Voucher` and `Voucher_2` tables that which one I should use for my Database.

The tables output is following

[My tables Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Sr4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one seems serviceable. Are you given example *queries* that should be run over your system? If so, have you tried writing those queries and seeing whether one or other of your structures makes all of those queries harder or simpler? Also, have you considered what *integrity* constraints you may wish the database to enforce?

For instance, finding the current balance of an account can be reasonably performed using either structure.:

```
SELECT
   ac.AcNumber,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DrCr = 'Cr' THEN Amount
                             ELSE -Amount END) as Balance
FROM
   Accounts ac
      inner join
   Voucher v
      on
         ac.AcID = v.AccountNo
WHERE
  ac.AcNumber = 1010
GROUP BY
  ac.AcNumber

SELECT
   ac.AcNumber,
   SUM(CASE WHEN V2DebitAc = V2CreditAc THEN 0
            WHEN V2CreditAc = ac.AciD   THEN Amount
                                        ELSE -Amount END) as Balance
FROM
   Accounts ac
      inner join
   Voucher_2 v
      on
         ac.AcID = v.V2DebitAc or
         ac.AcID = v.V2CreditAc
WHERE
  ac.AcNumber = 1010
GROUP BY
  ac.AcNumber
```

If all transactions are required to be *balanced*, how will you ensure that there are always pairs of rows in `Voucher` that match each other?

If you have to apply interest of other account corrections, what account will you match those with in `Voucher_2`?

If you haven't been given any scenarios to work against, try to conjure some up like the above and see how well they fit. Without further information though, I'd say either will probably work.

---

One thing I'd serious recommend fixing though - having all of AcNumber, AccountNum and AcID seems like a recipe for confusion. I'd probably just use `AcID` everywhere outside of the `Accounts` table unless you want to go one step further and just use `AcNumber` as a natural key and use it *everywhere* and remove `AcID` from the picture. Certainly I didn't expect (before writing the queries) that I'd find `AccountNum` also in the picture and it's *not* the same thing as `AcNumber`.

Where possible I'd advise using as few *names* as possible. Ideally, everywhere in your schema that you encounter a *particular* column name, it should mean the same concept, and you shouldn't encounter the same concept under any other names.

Comment: I have tried following code to retrieve debit and credit balance from one account but also stuck in getting running balance

select AcNumber, TrnDate,
case when voucher.[DrCr]='Dr' then amount else 0 end as 'Debit',
case when Voucher.[DrCr]='Cr' then amount else 0 end as 'Credit'
from Accounts
join Voucher
on Accounts.acid = voucher.accountno
join Transactions
on Transactions.TrnRef = Voucher.TranRef
where AcNumber=1010

I just want to know which table is correct for posting the transactions from voucher table and voucher_2 table

Comment: It's not accurate to write 'always pairs of rows in Voucher that match each other' - rather, 'the balance of all the rows in Voucher which have a common transaction should be zero'. Transactions can (and frequently do) have more than two lines.

Comment: @No'amNewman - I was giving *examples* of constraints that may apply. This is a toy example. I was trying to make it clear that the `Voucher_2` design *inherently* matches transactions where if that's a requirement of the system, more work is required to make that happen with `Voucher`.